# parallel code by parfor is slower than serial version by for

Tags: matlab, parallel-processing, genetic-algorithm

I have written a code by matlab and i've used parallel computing toolbox
more description about my code:
i'm trying to implement parallel genetic algorithm by matlab and parallel computing toolbox.

i've implemented that but i've a problem. that is my parallel code with parfor is so much slower that serial one with for.

my code:

```
tic

for j=1:maxIteration
    parfor i=1:numIslands
        if migrationInterval
            doMigration;
        end
        doCrossover;
        doMutation;
        newSpring;
    end 
end
toc
```

`numIslands` is always small number (5 to 12)
`maxiteration` is always big number (1500 to 5000)
please help me
thank you

Comment: my PC has a CPU with two cores

Comment: What do you get when you run [`gcp`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/distcomp/gcp.html)`('nocreate').NumWorkers`? Do your timing results change if you add [`parpool`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/distcomp/parpool.html)`(2);` before your loop?

Comment: Can you please include the details of how your pool is setup?  Also what is `migrationInterval`?  What determines if it's true or false?

Comment: Could you edit your question to use a code block? It will make it easier for us to read. Indent each line of code with 4 spaces.

Comment: Are you by chance using global variables? Is `migrationInterval` a very big variable? Do the sub functions load files? Are you sure the `parpool` has been set up? Any of those could be clues.

Comment: @AndrewPiliser , I'm using MATLAB R2012a. It don't know gcp and parpool.

Comment: @Matt , i use this code: matlabpool('open',2). I'm sorry i had a type mistake in my code i'll fix that in next comment.

Comment: @AndrewPiliser,  I'm so sorry i had a type mistake in my code. I changed that. I think the reduction of speed is beacuse of locating parfor inside for.

Comment: @Matt , as I told you before i had a type mistake in my code, I changed that. I think the reduction of speed is beacuse of locating parfor inside for.

Comment: @chessofnerd , migrationInterval is a condition, in 5th, 10th, 15th and... iteration of first for loop, the function doMigration is run.

Comment: @chessofnerd , I can't put all of my code here. it's so long and it has a lot of functions. but i can send it by email

Comment: @monir, thabk you for the code block. Looks a lot better! I'm confused at your workflow. It looks like you are doing the same work each iteration because the loop indicies are not being used. How does one loop iteration differ from the next?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to run your function using "Run and Time" tool. The results will show, if the reason is in parfor-procedure or in your function.
It can be the parfor procedure is unnecesary and gives no advantage, but it depends always on the function you run.

Comment: thanks for your answer. can you give me a reference for using "Run and Time" tool. is there this tool in MATLAB R2012a?

Comment: http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/profiling-for-improving-performance.html  - here is a guide how to use profiler (or Run and Time) tool.

Answer (score 0):

You mention that your CPU has two cores. One problem might being the code itself, it looks as if you are calling scripts instead of functions, so you might be flooding your workspace unnecessarily by doing so. Furthermore, if any of those scripts is declaring variables on the fly, you might be clogging your RAM (Matlab is particularly good at that) thus making your code run slower.

Try to optimize each of the scripts first.

I would really recommend you to use functions instead of scripts though.